# I can't get this to work: In Sublime Text (3), I am trying to alternate a setting's value using the same shortcut/keymap and contexts

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3, I am trying to alternate a setting's value using the same shortcut, but with differing contexts. Basically, I want to alternate the `draw_white_space` setting between its three possible values: `none`, `selection`, and `all`.

I change the setting easily enough with three separate shortcuts/keymaps. Here is that code (working):

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+e", "ctrl+w"],
    "command": "set_setting",
    "args": {
        "setting": "draw_white_space",
        "value": "all",
    }
},
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+e", "ctrl+q"],
    "command": "set_setting",
    "args": {
        "setting": "draw_white_space",
        "value": "none",
    }
},
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+e", "ctrl+s"],
    "command": "set_setting",
    "args": {
        "setting": "draw_white_space",
        "value": "selection",
    }
}
```

But, what I would really like is to be able to press `["ctrl+e", "ctrl+w"]` and have it alternate through each possible value. Yes, it is a Visual Studio shortcut that I'm used to!

I created what looks to me like it should work, but it doesn't. At least not how I want it to. Here is that code (broken):

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+e", "ctrl+w"],
    "command": "set_setting",
    "args": {
        "setting": "draw_white_space",
        "value": "none",
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "setting.draw_white_space", 
          "operator": "equal", "operand": "all" }
    ]
},
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+e", "ctrl+w"],
    "command": "set_setting",
    "args": {
        "setting": "draw_white_space",
        "value": "selection",
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "setting.draw_white_space",
          "operator": "equal", "operand": "none" }
    ]
},
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+e", "ctrl+w"],
    "command": "set_setting",
    "args": {
        "setting": "draw_white_space",
        "value": "all",
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "setting.draw_white_space",
          "operator": "equal", "operand": "selection" }
    ]
}
```

I have tested out my contexts, so I know they work. For instance, I can manually set `all` in my settings file, then the shortcut that checks for `all` will work the first time only. It nor the others will work after that.

Another thing I noticed is that my settings file does not change the `draw_white_space` value when the shortcut does work (including the three separate shortcuts). I assumed that might be default behavior - the settings changes may be per session - and that would be fine. But, I removed the setting completely and it is still the same behavior.

I am changing the file opened via the `Preferences` | `Key Bindings - User` menu, which opened the `<Sublime Text>\Data\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` file.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: Have no idea why `{ "key": "setting.draw_white_space", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "all" }` always be `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not what you want, but you can get that behavior with a pretty simple plugin.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class CycleDrawWhiteSpaceCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        white_space_type = view.settings().get("draw_white_space")

        if white_space_type == "all":
            view.settings().set("draw_white_space", "none")
        elif white_space_type == "none":
            view.settings().set("draw_white_space", "selection")
        else:
            view.settings().set("draw_white_space", "all")
```

After you save the plugin, bind your key binding to `cycle_draw_white_space`

Comment: Wow, thank you! That works fantastic and just what I was looking for! I don't know what caused/causes my original issue, but this solved my request better than I expected!

Comment: Thank you again, @skuroda! I polished it up (with what I know about creating Sublime Text plugins so far) and put it up on github. It does exactly what I want and I learned a lot about creating plugins too! Thanks again! https://github.com/kodybrown/SublimeCycleWhiteSpace